# Full Text Search for extracting a snippet of the text (returning intended text and it's surrounding)

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, filetable

I'm using SQL file table and for instance I have a saved text file named "SOS.txt" which contains following text

`For god's sake, save us right now please. We can't survive.
Now or never!`

Now I want to find all files that contain the word `save`, so I execute following query

```
SELECT * FROM FileTableExample
WHERE CONTAINS(file_stream, 'save')
```

and here's the result:
[image: The snapshot from result]

```
stream file => 0x616C692053617665207573207269676874206E6F772E0D0A4E6F77206F72206E6576657221
```

As you can see I got the true result, the third column of the result indicates the file under name `SOS.txt`, I have the stream_id and stream_file but what I'm about to find is the way to show the the intended text in company with it's surrounding in human readable format.
Somethings like this:

```
   Name      |     Excerpt
-------------+----------------------
 SOS.txt     |..sake, save us..
```

Is there any way?

**Update:**

After searching on the net I found [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/hit-highlighting-in-full-text-search) article which is useful but it didn't mention about full text search in filetable structure.

Based on [this](https://www.oakdome.com/programming/SQL_FileTables_FullTextSearch.php) article, I converted file stream to string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(MAX), file_stream) AS Excerpt, *
from FileTableExample
where contains(file_stream, 'save')
```

[image]

It works if the file is a plain text like SOS.txt but if it's .docx or .pptx file, you are not going to gain a useful convention.

Comment: Do u have Full text search enabled ?

Comment: Yeah , I do, that's the reason why I can search among plain text files, office documents like Word, PowerPoint, Excel .. and PDF files, thanks to iFilters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, CAST(file_Stream as varchar(max))

Comment: The problem still exists, it doesn't return true conversion when the file is an office document or PDF file. In my case the conversion result was PK + 3 weird characters.